# VPN Connection: It connects but no access to remote network resources and shows as Private rather than Domain

Tags: windows, vpn, radius, windows-sbs-2011, resources

I have a puzzling issue that I cannot find an answer for.

I'm trying to connect a Win 10 (1909) machine to a VPN running on SBS 2011, via a RADIUS server.  The client connects OK, apart from I don't have access to any of the resources on the network, I cannot ping any of the addresses on the remote network.  In Network and Sharing Centre it shows as a Public or Private Network instead of mydomain.local. When this client machine is connected via an ethernet cable it works fine, no access issues at all.

Another machine also running Win 10 (1909) connects to the VPN absolutely fine and has full access to the network resources and can ping any machine on the network.

The VPN is using IKE2 and EAP to connect.

I don't think it is relating to the RADIUS or the VPN settings but more something on the local machine. 
I am going to attempt disconnecting it from the domain and reconnecting it.

Thanks
Andy.

EDIT:

I have also discovered it is a user profile issue. One of my other colleagues came back into the office and they have the same problem so, I grabbed his machine and logged on with my user profile (We don't use roaming profiles)  and my profile on their machine (also 1909) gives me access to the network resources.

Update: 19/03/2020

The problem is with User Profiles. I removed one of the affected machines user profile and logged back in while physically connected by ethernet to the domain and the new profile is working as expected. Isolated it from the network, used my tethered hotspot and connected to the VPN, connected detects the domain correctly and full access to the network resources.

The affected machines are all Win7 to Win10 upgrades.

Update 20/03/2020

I also tried the reg fix from here
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4550028/firewall-profile-does-not-switch-to-domain-when-using-third-party-vpn

didn't affect anything.
couldn't see anything in the registry relating to the user profile.

All the affected machines have now had their profiles removed and recreated by logging on to the domain.

Comment: *When this client machine is connected via an ethernet cable it works fine, no access issues at all.*  Is your testing through wireless?  Is the wireless external to the LAN hosting the VPN?  Or, when you say connected via ethernet, do you mean connected to the LAN?  (E.g. a laptop that works connected to the organization network but when attempting to VPN from home, it does not work.)

Comment: Not using wireless at all. The machine is connected to the LAN normally via Ethernet. I'm testing the VPN using a USB tethered connection from my mobile.

Comment: I have also discovered it is a user profile issue. One of my other colleagues came back into the office and they have the same problem so, I grabbed his machine and logged on with my user profile (We don't use roaming profiles)  and my profile on their machine (also 1909) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue on the machines by the removing the user profile and letting windows build a new one when logging in to the domain.

Advanced System Properties->User Profiles was used from Safe Mode to remove the affected profile on the affected machines.

All was working on the new profile.

I don't know quite what was causing it, apart from a legacy from updating from windows